# System.TimeoutException occure in windows phone

Tags: .net, web-services, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

[image]I am calling web service in my windows phone 8 application.Its working fine  but some times  it gets to receive data I get this timeout exception.(due to slow network or some other proble).so this time my application is not handled and it give =exception like bellow.

An exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

How can i handle this exception. no idea what to do.

My C# Code is

```
 bool isAvailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
 if (isAvailable == true)
 {
     try
     {                        
         WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient ws = new WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient();
         ws.LoginUserJsonCompleted += ws_LoginUserJsonCompleted;
         ws.LoginUserJsonAsync(txtloginUserName.Text, pass, "1");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     { }
 }

void ws_LoginUserJsonCompleted(object sender, WhatsupServices.LoginUserJsonCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         //webservice responce
          string Result = e.Result;
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe post a little more... This is like say "My car usualy drives but sometimes it doesn't"

Comment: @IvanCrojachKaračić:see my edited question

Comment: you can take your methods which calls web services inside of a try-catch block and catch the **TimeoutException()**? isn't that sufficient?

Comment: @BeytanKurt:thanks for replying but its not working my catch not handle this exception

Comment: Could you please add a short code snippet of how you call the service where you take the timeout.

Comment: @BeytanKurt:see my edited question.....when wab service time out at that time my responce not come...i mean ws_LoginUserJsonCompleted method is not come

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried a simple example, didn't have any problem. hope someone else can help you.

Comment: Can any one know solution ?